# Customize a Qt Tree Widget

Tags: qt4

Is it possible to customize a tree widget so that the full row will be selected and also move the items a little to the left so that there will not be that much white space?

I would like it to get it looking like this:

[image]

Instead of the default look that is this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you perhaps are looking for is setIndentation() which currently defaults to 20 pixels.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qtreeview.html#indentation-prop